# Google Flights CFHTTP not working

Tags: coldfusion, cfhttp

I am trying to get the following URL with CFHTTP but I am not getting the page. Any ideas?

http://www.google.com/flights/#search;f=JNB;t=MRU;d=2016-12-19;sel=JNBMRU0MK854;s=0

```
<cfhttp url="https://www.google.com/flights/##search;f=JNB;t=MRU;d=2016-12-19;sel=JNBMRU0MK852;s=0" method="GET" resolveurl="true" useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.87 Safari/537.36">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="HTTP_REFERER" value="http://example.com/feed/" >
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Accept-Encoding" value="gzip,deflate,sdch" >
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Proxy-Connection" value="keep-alive" >
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Accept" value="application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Accept-Language" value="en-US,en;q=0.8">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Accept-Charset" value="ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3">
    <cfhttpparam type="cookie" name="some-cookie" value="1">
</cfhttp>
<cfoutput>#cfhttp.filecontent#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: What do you get instead?

Comment: Why would my question be down voted?

Answer (score 1):

Using `http` instead of `https` worked for me.
If you want to test it, use the method suggested by  @bkbk.

`<cfdump var="#cfhttp.filecontent#">`

But do note that, outputing the `filecontent` will not work similar to the original site. This is because the site uses some security header like

```
x-content-type-options:nosniff
x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection:1; mode=block
```

Which will not allow loading of few of the original site scripts and css.

Comment: Thank you. I can display the result using `<cfdump>` but I need to get to the html. I need to scrape the flight information from the result. Looking through the dump, there is no way that I can use it effectively that I can see, unless I am missing something? [http://www.google.com/flights/#search;f=JNB;t=MRU;d=2016-12-19;sel=JNBMRU0MK854;s=0] shows what I need.

Comment: <cfhttp >

    </cfhttp>
    <cffile action="write" file="#expandpath('flightSchedule.html')#" output="#cfhttp.filecontent#">
Done. Now open link <a href="flightSchedule.html">Flight Schedule</a>

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that the response is coming in as HTML, but your browser isn't displaying the tags. To display a result you can see, use

```
<cfoutput>#xmlformat(cfhttp.filecontent)#</cfoutput>
```

or

```
<cfdump var="#cfhttp#">
```

As an aside, what about just running

```
<cfhttp url="https://www.google.com/flights/##search;f=JNB;t=MRU;d=2016-12-19;sel=JNBMRU0MK852;s=0" method="GET" resolveurl="true" useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.87 Safari/537.36" />
```